# C: How to manually add a dependency when compiling a Kernel module

Tags: c, linux, module, dependencies, kernel

I'm working on an embedded Linux system that has a specific I2C platform driver and I'm writing a custom I2C driver. Everything works fine, but I have a problem with their dependencies.

As my custom driver uses the default I2C functions, once I compile it, the make command automatically updates the *modules.dep* file saying that my driver depends on *i2c-core* to run, but that is not enough. In order to *i2c-core* to be configured I need to load *i2c-omap* first (the platform's driver) and only then my driver works properly.

Unfortunately, I can't find any dummy function to call and thus trick the make into adding another dependency when it generates my driver. Also, I would prefer an automated solution instead of modifying *modules.dep* with something like *sed -i 's/RE1/RE2/' modules.dep*.

So, is there any way to explicitly add a dependency to a module when I compile it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer here: http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch11.html

I solved my problem calling

```
request_module("i2c-omap");
```

Anyway, this does not exactly update the dependencies file as I first intended. If anyone knows a way to do that, please add a comment here!

Comment: Well, there is yet another way: just create an entry inside /etc/modprobe.d/driver.conf with the following text:

"softdep my_driver pre: plat_driver"

and modprobe will load the platform driver before loading the custom driver